# GCP Discovery.build() Library Breaking Cloud Function without repeatable pattern

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-iam

I am using a discovery.build() method to built the IAM Client Library as such. Because there is no python client library for IAM that has the capability to list service accounts and their keys.. Which is crazy to me! See this for IAM python client: https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/iam/latest , which is very limited. Thus, I have to use discovery.build().

```
iam = discovery.build("iam", "v1")  # Build IAM library
```

Inside of a Cloud Function. This function runs great most of the time. However, at times I get this extremally strange error:

Traceback (most recent call last): File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2073, in wsgi_app response = self.full_dispatch_request() File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1518, in full_dispatch_request rv = self.handle_user_exception(e) File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1516, in full_dispatch_request rv = self.dispatch_request() File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1502, in dispatch_request return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args) File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/functions_framework/**init**.py", line 123, in view_func function(event) File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/functions_framework/**init**.py", line 67, in wrapper return func(*args, **kwargs) File "/workspace/main.py", line 432, in entry_point d.handler() File "/workspace/main.py", line 101, in handler self.parse_sa() # Call the next method , funneling down to service accounts in the project File "/workspace/main.py", line 128, in parse_sa .execute() File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/googleapiclient/_helpers.py", line 130, in positional_wrapper return wrapped(*args, **kwargs) File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 923, in execute resp, content = _retry_request( File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 222, in _retry_request raise exception File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 191, in _retry_request resp, content = http.request(uri, method, *args, **kwargs) File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google_auth_httplib2.py", line 218, in request response, content = self.http.request( File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/httplib2/**init**.py", line 1724, in request (response, content) = self._request( File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/httplib2/**init**.py", line 1444, in _request (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers) File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/httplib2/**init**.py", line 1367, in _conn_request conn.request(method, request_uri, body, headers) File "/layers/google.python.runtime/python/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1283, in request self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked) File "/layers/google.python.runtime/python/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1329, in _send_request self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked) File "/layers/google.python.runtime/python/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1278, in endheaders self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked) File "/layers/google.python.runtime/python/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1038, in _send_output self.send(msg) File "/layers/google.python.runtime/python/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 999, in send self.sock.sendall(data) File "/layers/google.python.runtime/python/lib/python3.10/ssl.py", line 1237, in sendall v = self.send(byte_view[count:]) File "/layers/google.python.runtime/python/lib/python3.10/ssl.py", line 1206, in send return self._sslobj.write(data) ssl.SSLEOFError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:2426)

Previously, I used the discovery.build() for secrets managed and cloud resource manager. At times throughout the duration, the script would fail at different methods, without any rhyme or reason. Recently I switched over to their python clients to see if the discovery.build() is the problem, which I believe it is.

Given there is no IAM Python Client that allows the user to list the service accounts and keys, I see the discovery.build() as the only way. It appears the error is failing to build the layers of the discoverd.build("iam").

I even initiated the library in a "lazy variable outside" of the function!

Very confused, and any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you check if this [breaking changes](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/blob/main/UPGRADING.md) affect your function?

Comment: Hmmm.. I am on 2.7.3 python api client, and 3.10 python version. So I do not believe this would affect my use case.

Comment: Have you tried updating [`google-api-python-client` to `2.91.0`](https://pypi.org/project/google-api-python-client/) and [`google-cloud-iam` to `2.12.0`](https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-iam/) as the latest versions?

Comment: well, the google-cloud-iam client is pretty useless in my scripts objectives. Google-Cloud-IAM is limited in its use cases for some reason. I needed to list service accounts and keys, so the discovery library was required. I haven't tried updating to 2.91.0 yet though!

Comment: are you aware of anything in the change logs that could improve my expereince from 2.7.3 to 2.91.0?

Comment: Please check [`google-cloud-iam` changelogs](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/iam/latest/changelog) for the complete list of all the features and bug fixes for every version update.

Comment: Did any of my previous comments address your concern?